# asp.net mvc get route corresponding url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes

I faced with the following problem. I have an url and I would like to check whether the url could be mapped to any route defined in my RouteConfig or not. In other words I need a right way to determine whether the url is correct for my application or not.

Maybe anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
For Example : Student is my contoller and having action method     StudentList then I need to write following code in RouteConfig.cs file.

StudentContoller.cs

        public List<Student> StudentList (StudentModel model)
        {
            /* Logic for Student List */
         return View(model);
        }


      RouteConfig.cs

     routes.MapRoute(
                name: "StudentList",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Student", action ="StudentList", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
```